# Methods for using HTTP Keep-alive on HTTP requests

Tags: linux, performance, http, optimization, keep-alive

I have been reading up on web-site performance lately and along side lowering HTTP-Requests there is another major factor in web-performance.

**Keep-alive connections between the server and the client.**

Now as I am on shared hosting I very much doubt KA connections are possible but i will soon me setting up my own linux testbed server at home to run my blog off for a few weeks while running different optimisations on the site.

One of those being KA before I take the plunge and buy myself a year of nice shiney hosting from [media-temple](http://mediatemple.net/webhosting/ve/) for myself and my clients.

---

*Does anyone have any experience with KA connections on a normal web-site and if so what are the performance gains (rough figures) you saw from these optimisations?*

I would like to know **what are the methods of implementing KA from a linux server standpoint** and **is KA more router/firewall centric, server-side code based or kernel based**?

Comment: Don't know about other servers, but keep-alive is [on by default](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#keepalive) in Apache so you don't really have to do anything.

Comment: @Martin apparently not on my server, I ran a sort of "web-speed test" indicating that NONE of my files served up had KA-connections...

Comment: Ok, but if you're running Apache it's as simple as `KeepAlive On` in your conf. It's easy to verify keep-alive with Firebug or similar - you should see a `Connection: Keep-Alive` header in the request, and the same header in the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Keep-Alives are a features of the HTTP Application layer and are not affected by the kernel or normal routers/firewalls.  However, NAT routers (any consumer router is an NAT router) impose limits on how long a connection can be idle before it is dropped.  Many good NAT routers allow 5 minutes or more, but some particularly bad NAT routers can be 60 seconds or less.  In general, HTTP Keep-Alives are best for 15 seconds or less and are used to allow multiple requests to be handled in the same TCP connection such as what happens when a webpage with multiple images, stylesheets, and other content is downloaded.  It is especially useful with SSL since it takes a lot more time and resources to start a new SSL connection and Keep-Alives allow the same SSL connection to be used multiple times.